# Fill in multiple inputs of exe console app with a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

First of all, it's not sending arguments to the exe.

I have a third party config exe which is a console application which I execute with some argument

```
call config.exe restart
```

After this app is waiting for the input and here's the place where I stuck.

```
Enter personal access token:
```

I need just to send an empty line and after that, a couple of other prompts for input will appear.

```
echo
echo someText
echo someOtherText
```

exe is working so obviously batch won't be executed as I want.

How to execute batch kind of in parallel with exe so it will fill in those inputs?

Comment: Thanks, @Gerhard looks like it's what I need, just one more question, how to pass an empty line in this way like manually just press enter? Because '''echo | echo someText | config.cmd remove''' with first "echo" pass a space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it with something line this:

```
(
echo(
echo someText
echo someOtherText
) | config.exe restart
```

where `echo(` will echo a blank line.

**Edit** as per the now deleted comments, your .net app had the incorrect function implemented. they needed to use `Console.Read`. Only the developer can fix it, unless your have the source code.

Comment: I got an error like this `Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected. Try Console.Read.`

Comment: Do you know any way to access `Console.Read`?

Comment: Nah, that's some legacy thing that is older than I am